# eGit fails to import a repo using https URL

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am getting the following error when trying to clone Git repo using egit and eclipse:

[image]

Here's what I managed to do so far:

1. Cloning using ssh works but not https
2. Cloning using https and ssh works from the command line on the same URL.

So, this must be an egit / eclipse problem.

Proxy is not configured in eclipse nor do I need one configured to clone this repo.

When I set http.sslVerify = false in gitconfig as suggeested by the error it doesn't help and i'm getting the same error.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the Error Log view contain about this error?

Comment: I couldn't find anything relevant for this error but perhaps I'm not looking at the right place. Can you direct me please?

Comment: Press Cmd+3 and type Error Log to open the view. No message in there?

Comment: Right here's what it says Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching

Comment: Sorry correction Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)

Comment: I'm starting to think it might be the JDK eclipse points to...

Comment: Looks like it could be solved by upgrading the JRE with which you run Eclipse to Java 8, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_faq.html#javadh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by installing the 64 but version of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, solved it by providing Personal Access Key instead of password.

Ref: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/